# ProgressDialogs and material design spec

Tags: android, progressdialog, material-design

From [this comment](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/#comment-1982923608):

> ProgressDialogs are a bad pattern, and are not even mentioned in the
>   material design spec, which is why I haven't backported them.

Can anybody tell how to show  my app is doing network transaction with `material design spec` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think an Activity Indicator would be most appropriate here, unless you implement your own design.

> Activity indicators are for operations of an indeterminate length.
>   They ask users to wait a moment while something finishes up, without
>   getting into specifics about what's happening behind the scenes.

This comes straight from the Material design spec, the Gmail application uses the Activity circle while loading it's data.

Source: https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html

Comment: "This comes straight from the Material design spec" I do not think so, but thanks.